# Where is my delegate outlet on my view controller?

Tags: storyboard

I was reading some tutorials that said to use the delegate outlet on your storyboard and mine just isn't there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (I'm trying to close the keyboard when the return button is hit)

Comment: You'll have to provide more context for this question. Not everything has a "delegate" (e.g. a simple view doesn't). But you can still have reference outlets for them. Or are you talking about some UI control that really does have a delegate outlet (e.g. a text field or a table view)?

Comment: So you are talking about a UITextField? You really don't see its `delegate` outlet?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your view controller class need to define `IBOutlet  ClassType* name;` Where `ClassType` is type of class name e.g. `NSButtonCell`.
2. You can right click on UI object and click on the + sign and drag-n-drop this to your `IBOutlet ClassType* name;`